# Mysql COUNT and IF usage

Tags: mysql, sql

I have MySQL table with structure:

```
| uid     |   itemid
| -------------------
| 1001    |   9999
| 1001    |   8888
| 2002    |   8888
| ...     |   ...
```

**uid** and **itemid** not unique columns. Bun uid+itemid is unique combination.

I need count rows by itemid. I use next query:

```
SELECT itemid, COUNT(*) 
FROM unlikes 
WHERE itemid IN ('9999', '8888') GROUP BY itemid;
```

And this works!

Next, i need to know which row have concrete uid. I use:

```
SELECT itemid, COUNT(*), IF (uid = '1001', TRUE, FALSE) toggled 
FROM unlikes 
WHERE itemid IN ('9999', '8888') GROUP BY itemid;'
```

Not work. If i have more than one row with itemid = 8888, than toggled = FALSE. I need toggled = TRUE if one in group have uid = 1001;

Comment: Replace `IF (uid = '1001', TRUE, FALSE)` by `sum( case when uid = '1001' then 1 else 0 ) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT itemid, COUNT(*), 
CASE WHEN uid = 1001 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE end AS toggled 
FROM unlikes 
WHERE itemid IN ('9999', '8888') GROUP BY itemid;
```

Comment: i find this solution: `COUNT(IF(uid=1001,NULL)) AS toggled` its bad?

Comment: In case of `9999` with `1001` also returns `TRUE` using the above query. Correct?

Comment: @SLonoed . . . The CASE statement is standard SQL and available in most databases.  Your expression (or the even simpler SUM(uid <> 1001)) is not standard and specific to MySQL (and perhaps a few other databases).